# every std::cin from AllocConsole combines

Tags: c++, windows, dll, std, cin

Working on a DLL here, using `AllocConsole` to create a console window.
To initialize the console, I used this code below:

```
// attempt to allocate console window
if (!AllocConsole())
{
    MessageBox(0, L"Couldn't create console window.", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    return FALSE;
}

// open window
FILE* file;
freopen_s(&file, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
freopen_s(&file, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
freopen_s(&file, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
std::cout.clear();
std::clog.clear();
std::cerr.clear();
std::cin.clear();

// the rest of the code goes here

// close window
fclose(file);
FreeConsole();
```

I query for input normally, and it works:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
```

However, if I run that same code again later when I'm looking for another user input, it will actually combine the two of the inputs. This stacks over and over again for every user input.

I've tried running `std::cin.clear()` again after every input but obviously that doesn't work.

Is there any way to fix this so that they don't stack?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's because you are leaking file handles to stdin (and stderr).

You are opening three file handles on each iteration, but only closing one.

Instead of this:

```
FILE* file;
freopen_s(&file, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
freopen_s(&file, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
freopen_s(&file, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
```

Havea  different variable for each file, and initialize to NULL since you are not checking the result of `freopen_s`

```
FILE* fileOut = NULL;
FILE* fileErr = NULL;
FILE* fileIn = NULL;
freopen_s(&fileOut, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
freopen_s(&fileErr, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
freopen_s(&fileIn, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
```

And then at the end, close all three files.  Use `fclose`, not `close`. I assume that's a typo.  Do this:

```
fclose(fileOut);
fclose(FileErr);
fclose(FileIn);
```

Comment: This did not fix.

Comment: Oh well, I tried. At least you got your file handle leak fixed.